# aws s3 cp: don't copy if file is already there

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two requirements for copying files from one bucket to another:

1. **Logical**: copy the website redirect from the source file to the destination file for each file. (If s3://bucket-src/x.txt has website redirect /foo.txt and s3://bucket-src/y.txt has website redirect /bar.txt, then the final result is s3://bucket-dest/x.txt has website redirect /foo.txt and s3://bucket-dest/y.txt has website redirect /bar.txt)
2. **Performance**: if the file with the same data is already in the destination bucket, don't do anything for that file.

[`cp`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) satisfies requirement 1. [`sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) satisfies requirement 2. Is there any way to get requirement 1 from `sync` or requirement 2 from `cp`?

Comment: Can you expand on what exactly requirement 1 is? What does it mean to "copy the website redirect" in this context? It's not clear to me what you are saying the `cp` command can do, that the `sync` command won't do.

Comment: Following @MarkB 's comment, sync should satisfy both of the requirements. Recursively copies new and updated files from the source directory to the destination. from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: I've updated my question to elaborate on req 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is: No, there not a command to do specifically that. You will either have to rename your local file prior to uploading or handle each file separately.

You could get the md5 of the remote file and compare it with the local md5, if they don't match you perform the `cp` command.

You could also perform a recursive `ls` and compare filesizes and use the `--include` switch to handle which files to sync.